# PHP ActiveRecord: How do I add multiple conditions?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to bind more than one condition in php [ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

How can I change the below code (which works) to bind another condition?

```
$events = Event::find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('event_type = ?', array('opera')),
    'select' => 'col1, col2, col3',
));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$events = Event::find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('event_type = ? AND event_hour = ?', 'opera', 'your_event_hour'),
    'select' => 'col1, col2, col3',
));
```

Comment: This worked for me in 2019, after 5 years? I just wanted to update an old code base I used phpactiverecord for. But it seems the project isn't running anymore and their official website is off. You can get more information from here if you still need phpactiverecord for whatever reasons. https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectChanges = Table_model::update_all(array(
    'set' => array(
      'field_to_update' => 'Y'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
      "sex= 'Male' && age <= 50"
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

for example if you have use and conditions you can use

```
event::all(array('conditions' => array('event_type = ? AND date = ?', 'opera', '06-06-2013')));
```

which produce sql

SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE event_type = 'pera' AND date = '06-06-2013';