# PHP ActiveRecord: How do I execute a query made with SQLBuilder?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964242/php-activerecord-how-do-i-add-multiple-conditions), but have now found that the problem with binding conditions in that method is it's very hard to programatically compile more complex queries...

I think I need to be using the [PHP ActiveRecord SQLBuilder](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/SQLBuilder) but I'm finding the documentation confusing. How do i actually execute a query i've 'built'?

This is their example code, but it doesn't actually show you how to return any data?!

```
$builder = new ActiveRecord\SQLBuilder($conn, "table_name");     
$builder->where("name = ?", "Hemingway");
echo $builder; /* => SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = ? */
```

Any help really appreciated :)

Comment: If you have an ActiveRecord model available, I think you can `Model::find_by_sql($builder)` ...

Comment: that gives me __Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'__

Comment: /* => SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = ? */ This looks like a prepared query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the model corresponding to table `table_name` is `ModelName` then:

```
$result_set = ModelName::find_by_sql($builder->to_s(), $builder->bind_values());
```

Comment: I get "Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound" ?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, you must also pass the values bound in the where call. I've edited the answer, binding mr. Hemingway to the query

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, i don't get an error from this but I still can't work out how to return the values? $conn->query() returns the PDOStatement Object

Comment: oups, untested code :) Connection is useful for updates and inserts, but yeah, you don't get a model object. You won't get one if you use PDO's  fetchAll(), either. Ok, again then, using the Model class - see the edited answer

Comment: so sorry about the rewrites, at the moment I don't have a working php-AR to test on

Answer (score -1):

haven't checked completely but following might be helpful

[ADODB Active Records for PHP](http://phplens.com/adodb/docs-active-record.htm)